# Analysis of set of lines intersecting one line in line in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, arcgis-10.6

I have a layer in ArcMap with a cluster of lines (polylines/shapefile) with file name "track_lines". I have another layer with three polylines (1, 2, 3), file name "crosslines". I would like ArcMap to calculate how many times line 3 from layer "crosslines" has intersected "track_lines" file, see picture.

Can I make a separate count of intersects for each crossline?

[image]

Comment: Employing the Intersect tool is one path to that. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Questions here should not only frame the task, but also detail what has been attempted, and what problem has been encountered.

Comment: @PolyGeo; I am now running the intersect. I have added both layers in the Input field. It did not ask me on which crosslines I would like to have the analysis.

Comment: Can a crossing be multiples from a single track? Or is it once per track?

Comment: @Hornbydd: Yes, the crossing can be multiple, e.g. if one track in "track_lines" crosses 5 times the "crossing" line number 3, then I should get 5 crossings/intersection on line 3 from a particular track. Some individual tracks crosses the crosslines multiple times.

Comment: Then I think the solution @PolyGeo suggested is the way to go. You can then use the summary statistics tool to group by crossing ID and route ID to get the count.

Comment: Thanks I will check if this works and let you guys know.